# How can I use pip3.9 on linux server if my default python is 3.6

Tags: python, linux, pip

In my linux server I have 3 versions of python2, python 3.6 and 3.9. The default is 3.6 and there are some packages in pip that are only available in new versions of pip, but the problem is that when I type command `pip3.9 install django` it returns an error `command pip3.9 is not defined`. So my question is how can I use pip3.9 or if I cant than how to delete that python3.6

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:
`python3.9 -m pip install django`

This is another way to use the pip command.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Pipfiles](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html) and [virtualenvs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for this.

Virtualenvs are a way of creating a custom python environment for a certain project. For example, you can specify that the python interpreter for a project that is used is Python 3.9 or Python 2.7.7.

After specifying your Python version, you can specify which version of a certain package you want - whether you want Version 1.0.1 of Django or Version 1.2.8 of Django, or whether you just want to use the default for Python 3.9 (which seems to be what you want).

Everything above is achieved with the help of Pipfiles. `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` are the files that `pip` (or rather `pipenv`) uses to keep track of the Python interpreter you use, the packages you use and their versions, and the versions of their dependencies.

But how do you *manage* all that information? Luckily the python devs have created a tool called [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) that manages that all for you. In fact, before it's existence, Python users had to use a tool called `venv` and `pip` separately, and had to manage all the package dependencies manually using a `requirements.txt`. `pipenv` instead generates Pipfiles, which then can be sent to a different computer so that it could install the ***exact same environment***. This makes it very easy to deploy and distribute your software.

While I recommend that you read a tutorial on `pipenv`, what I would do goes something along the lines of this:

```sh
pipenv --python 3.9 # use python 3.9 specifically
pipenv install django # install the default django version for 3.9
pipenv lock # generate the Pipfile.lock and check for any errors with the dependencies
```

You would then push your `git` repo (or whatever) to your server and then run:

```
pipenv sync # install packages specified in Pipfile.lock
pipenv shell # "spawn" the virtualenv in a shell
python foobar.py # run your script
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use virtual environments to set special environment with any version of Python or libraries you wish. Refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) link for instructions and that, for example, `pyvenv` script is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.6.html#deprecated-features) in Python 3.6+

As for Python versions, add as many as you wish. As soon as you have virtual environmentmm, each environment can be linked to Python version you wish, for example

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.9 <path/to/yourvirtualenv>
```

Answer (score 0):

For different Python version refer to [this](https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-versions-python-ubuntu/) link. As soon as you have Python versions required, you can use different environment for each setup as I mentioned in another comment above.